# I am getting number format exception for this code

Tags: java, arrays, exception, numberformatexception

I am getting this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null 
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542) 
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) 
>               at Test.main(Main.java:10)

For the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 
class Test {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int a[]=new int[10],flag=1;
             System.out.println("Enter The Nos.");
            for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
                a[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            int i=0;
            do{

                if(a[i]!=42)
                    System.out.println(a[i]);
                else{ flag=0;break;

                } i++;
            }while(flag==1);
        }
    }
```

It is running fine on eclipse but on other IDEs, it is giving this exception.

Comment: can you show me your input for this program?

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Try the code in my answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: Try printing out the result of "br.readLine()" before trying to convert it to an Integer.  This will give you a clue on how to fix the program.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line `a[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());`

You should check for `br.readLine() != null` before you do the above line.

You are trying to parse `null` as an integer. That is what the error suggests.

**Edit:**
As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), `readLine()` returns `null` if the end of the stream has been reached.

Your code should look something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a[]=new int[10],flag=1;
        System.out.println("Enter The Nos.");
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
            String num = br.readLine();
            if(num != null) {
                a[i]=Integer.parseInt(num);
            } else {
                //a[i] = 0;   // You might want to assign a[i] to some integer if the input number is null
            }
        }
        int i=0;
        do{

            if(a[i]!=42)
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            else{ flag=0;break; }
            i++;
        }while(flag==1 && i < 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but _why_ is the stream coming up null only in Eclipse?

Comment: Though remember NumberFormatException is thrown if the String does not contain a parsable int. Including null though, which is the case here as Ashutosh mentioned :)

Comment: It is not the "stream coming up null".  Rather it is readline that is >>returning<< null.  And the reason for this is documented in the javadoc: you have reached the end-of-stream position.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar in this particular case, it is happening because of null. *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null*

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. But now, it is giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if a[i]!=42 is true for full array. That is, if 42 is not found in array, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arises.

Comment: @AvneetSingh you need to check if `i<10` in your `do-while` loop, otherwise `i` might be greater than 9 in which case you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Check the edited code with the condition in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is well descriptive, you are trying to parse null as an int. do a null check before you invoke parseInt().Its good to check the null ability of br like

```
br.readLine() != null
```

then parse it.

Your input may contains a space so java can't convert that to a number e.g,"4 5" ,for this you can replace all the spaces with "" and then try to convert that to the number.

```
br.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

your code will be look like as below,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a[]=new int[10],flag=1;
        System.out.println("Enter The Nos.");
    if(br.readLine()!=null)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
            String num = br.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            if(num != null) {
                a[i]=Integer.parseInt(num);
            } else {
                //a[i] = 0;   // You might want to assign a[i] to some integer if the input number is null
            }
        }
        int i=0;
        do{

            if(a[i]!=42)
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            else{ flag=0;break; }
            i++;
        }while(flag==1 && i < 10);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But these 2 statements are not working. Maybe I am too poor at that. Could you please place these statements at right place in my code